# How to scrape next line of HTML

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to scrape a code from a table within HTML. As it is in a table, they all share the same tags so I am having trouble finding another way to isolate that string. The way I am using is temperamental.

The table element:

```
<table class="factsheet-table table-no-border spacer-bottom">
…
<tbody>
…(to the required line)
<tr class="table-alt">

                <th class="align-left">
                    ISIN:
                </th>

                <td class="align-left">
                                            XS0105244585
                                    </td>

            </tr>

        quote_page = 'https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/t/tesco-6-2029'
        page = urlopen(quote_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        # Get Bond code
        search = re.compile('ISIN:')
        bond_code = soup.find(text=search).parent.find_next('td').contents[0]
        code = bond_code.strip()
```

I want to just get the code but the only way I can think of isolating it is by getting the next line of code after 'ISIN:'

I usually get a variation of 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute (parent/find_next…)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, it also worked for me.
Since there isn't anything else you could anchor your search on, i think using a text selector is acceptable.

However the website you're scraping sometimes doesn't respond with the page, but rather with an error message like this:

```html
<html><head>
<H1>Request Rejected</H1>
</head>
<body><P>The requested URL was rejected.</P>
<P>Please contact the Hargreaves Lansdown internet support team on 0116 800 8000 quoting reference: 1112223334445556667</P>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case it can't find your text regex and will fail.

You can fix this by simply retrying the entire block:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
from time import sleep


# retry 10 times
for attempt in range(10):
    quote_page = 'https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/t/tesco-6-2029'
    page = urlopen(quote_page).read()
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        search = re.compile('ISIN:')
        bond_code = soup.find(text=search)
        bond_code = bond_code.parent.find_next('td').contents[0]
        code = bond_code.strip()
        print("Found code:")
        print(code)
    except Exception as e:
        # log the error or simply pass
        print(e)
        print("Page was:")
        print(page)
        sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds before retrying
    else:
        break
else:
    # we failed all the attempts - deal with the consequences.
    print("Failed 10 times to get ISIN")
```

You can also use a python-library for retrying to make your code look nicer, e.g.:

- [retrying](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/)
- [retry](https://pypi.org/project/retry/)
- etc...

Comment: Thanks so much. Been struggling with this for a while so is a great help

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using a function `get_bond` for the query:

```
def get_bond(tag):
    return re.match('ISIN:', tag.text.strip())

quote_page = 'https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/t/tesco-6-2029'
page = urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Get Bond code
bond_code = soup.find(get_bond)

# Get ISIN code
isin_code = bond_code.find('td').text.strip()
print(isin_code)
```

`get_bond` enables us to select the main tag that encompasses `tr` and `td`, and then pick the necessary `td`.